# How to read a excel cell with formula Today() , using c#?

Tags: c#, excel

My excell cell is containing the formula Today(). and its displaying the value as mm/dd/yyyy format.Now i am trying to read the cell with c#.And my code is as below.

```
_InputData = objSheet.get_Range(colNo + rowNo ).Cells.Value;
```

The output is coming as mm/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM where as the excel cell was displaying only mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's because your excel sheet just reformat visually the value.
But underlying it's still the same representation.

If what you want is to format your string as "mm/dd/yyyy"
You can simply use the ToString method of a DateTime object.

```
//I'am guessing that _InputData is a type Object
_InputData = objSheet.get_Range(colNo + rowNo ).Cells.Value;
var timeValue = DateTime.Parse(_InputData).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: solution is looks good.But in practical for months 0-9 range is making problem.
Today() is returning *m/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM so when i am trying to concert the same its makeing another issue.


for 9/10/2016 12:00:00 AM , timeValue is getting value of 00/10/2016.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just trim it to the first space?  Is it a string getting returned?

If so:

```
_InputData = _InputData.Remove(_InputData.IndexOf(" "));
```

Comment: I cant do the trim as for different cases (ex. when formula is not using and simple text there in cell) it will make problem.